# Trying to understand Includes Method logic

Tags: google-apps-script

I have attempted the below script but it is returning the error message "cellRange[i][0].includes is not a function". I am wondering what I am doing wrong here? The idea is to highlight certain rows if the contents of the "cellRange" cells hit a match with the "chars" array.

```
var chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, generatorTab.getLastRow(), 1);
var cellRange = range.getValues();

for(i = 0; i<cellRange.length; i++){
    if(cellRange[i][0].includes(chars)) {
      sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("#00ffff");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `The idea is to highlight certain rows if the contents of the "cellRange" cells hit a match with the "chars" array.`, in this case, in the case of `cellRange[i][0].includes(chars)`, I thought that it should be `chars.includes(cellRange[i][0])`. But, in your script, the value of `i` is different row number from the matched row, because `cellRange` is retrieved from `sheet.getRange(2, 2, generatorTab.getLastRow(), 1)`. So, it is required to be also modified.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
if(cellRange[i][0].includes(chars)) {
  sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("#00ffff");
}
```

##### To:

```
if (chars.includes(cellRange[i][0])) {
  sheet.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, 2).setBackground("#00ffff");
}
```

Or, I thought that in your situation, when `setBackgrounds` is used, the process cost might be reduced a little as follows.

```
var chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B'];
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, generatorTab.getLastRow(), 1);
var cellRange = range.getValues();
var backgrounds = cellRange.map(([b]) => chars.includes(b) ? Array(2).fill("#00ffff") : Array(2).fill(null));
range.offset(0, -1, backgrounds.length, 2).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
```

#### Note:

- By the way, about `generatorTab.getLastRow()`, in this case, it's `sheet.getLastRow()`?

#### References:

- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

Comment: Ahh gotcha, this makes a lot of sense, thank you! I'll definitely explore the second option as well. Do you know why someone -1 my question?

Comment: Also, where can I find more information about this method: "Array(2)"

Comment: @Alexa Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When `setBackgrounds` is used instead of the use of `setBackground` in a loop, I thought that the process cost will become low. About `Also, where can I find more information about this method: "Array(2)"`, `Array(2).fill("#00ffff")` returns `["#00ffff", "#00ffff"]`. `Array(2)` create an array with 2 lengths. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) About `Do you know why someone -1 my question? `, I'm not sure. I apologize for this.